# Search value in body tag in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I want to implement search functionality, So my requirement is I want to search some keyword in body tag in all content page. I do not know how I can search keyword in body tag in Sitecore. Please guide me?

Comment: I guess it is wrong concept for Sitecore to search via page body tag. It is much more better to search via fields in items(that are displayed on page). Use Sitecore Search and Indexing Guide document to configure your search. This document can be easily found on sdn.sitecore.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Anton outlined, the concept of searching the Body tag is wrong for Sitecore. You want to think in terms of Content in fields of Items. Sitecore's ContentSearch is how you can achieve this.

Sitecore comes with default indexes out-of-the-box that you should use for the search. You should rebuild these via the Index Manager in the Content Editor and then base your search on the basic example I've outlined for you below.

```cs
    public IEnumerable<Item> Search(string searchterm)
    {
        string indexName = "sitecore_web_index";

        using (var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(indexName).CreateSearchContext())
        {
            var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultItem>();

            IQueryable<SearchResultItem> query = index.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(i => i.Content.Contains(searchterm)).Filter(predicate);

            var searchResults = query.GetResults();

            foreach (var hit in searchResults.Hits)
            {
                yield return hit.Document.GetItem();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

jRobbins's answer is sensible (he get's my upvote). However, it is technically possible to index the content of the body tag. I would be cautious with this. I've seen it working well,  but I've also seen it completely destroy the performance of a site.

The approach involves the creating a `computed field` in your index. You populate the computed field by making a web request to your newly published page and scraping the response body tag.

Here's are a couple of module that more or less does that:

- https://github.com/efocus-nl/sitecorewebsearch
- https://github.com/hermanussen/sitecore-html-crawler

If you can accept something a little less accurate, then you could loop through each of the components on your page and extract content from their datasources. That approach is discussed in this video:
http://www.techphoria414.com/Blog/2012/May/Sitecore_Page_Editor_Unleashed