# Most efficient way to get item by name in Sitecore 7?

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7

I have a `Droplist` field in an item that contains other items which are under the path `/sitecore/content/Home`. I need to get the selected item from the `Droplist`.

In this situation, I have to get the selected `Item` by its name. Are there any other efficient ways of doing this, or is the way I am doing this okay?

```
public static Item GetItemByName(string itemName)
{
    Database masterDb = Factory.GetDatabase("master");
    Item homeItem = masterDb.GetItem("/sitecore/content/Home");
    return homeItem.Axes.GetDescendants().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == itemName);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Droplist` is not the luckiest choice here. You should use `Droplink` instead - it stores the item as ID, instead of storing item name only.

You should avoid using name as item identifier. There can be multiple items with the same name, even under same parent.

`homeItem.Axes.GetDescendants()` is not really efficient method. It gets all the items which are under that node. You should avoid using it.

If you know that the item will be a child of the `homeItem`, you can use:

```cs
homeItem.Children.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == itemName)
```

If that item can be at any level under the `homeItem`, you can try to use index to get that item (checking item name equals to specified name and item full path starts with home page full path).

Answer (score 4):

This more of an information note than the answer .. @Marek 's answer is absolutely correct that you should use a `DropLink` instead so that you address the ID of the item directly.

Never (*never!* **Never!**) use `GetDescendants` in a call such as this (ie from `Home` downwards).I would try and avoid using it anywhere, ever :) [If i could burn `GetDescendants` out of the API I would :P]

If you think about it, you are starting at the `Home` node and then iterating down, visiting every single item as you go and it wont stop until it has touched every item, pulled every item from the DB and interrogated it. On a small dev site this opertation will be fast but as your solution gets bigger and bigger, as content editors create more and more items you will find you solution gets slower and slower and your SQL Server get more and more load (and you likely wont immediately know why !)

If you need to do a larger ranging query (i.e. to check a field on every item under the `home` node) then you should look at Sitecore's `ContentSearch` API as this is massively faster for doing these sorts of operations.

Answer (score 1):

As @Stephen Pope mentioned to most efficient way to search for an Item by Name is via the ContentSearch. I recently gave a [simple Content Search example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31409659/902125) which you can modify for your needs by add the following line to so that it searches Sitecore Item Names to find those with a matching name.

```cs
IQueryable<SearchResultItem> query = index.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(i => i.Name == itemName).Filter(predicate);
```

It is also worth following @Marek Musielak's advice and using Droplink over Droplist where possible so the value contained in the field is the ID of an Item instead of its Name which is far more useful in your development.

Answer (score 0):

Most of them have given the answers correctly. I would also suggest the same.

Droplink is always preferable to droplist because it stores the item ID instead of name. Droplink will give you a lot of flexibility over droplist.

GetDescendants - Loop through all the items and check so avoid as much as possible.instead use sitecore queries or fast queries which gives you more efficiency.

```
masterDb.SelectItems("fast:/sitecore/content/Home//*[@@templateid = '{F348C2A0-73B8-4AF4-BD9E-2C5901908369}']");
```

No one is going to store all the items in the same node. You would have created different type of items under home node. If you want to retrieve a specific set of items,Go for sitecore queries instead of getdescendants.